# Use Python to interact with existing instance of Google Chrome

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, operating-system

My aim is to scrape a website on Chrome using Selenium (or a similar module). However, an important aspect of the project is to avoid using a browser controlled by the test software, ie a browser opened using:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('...')
driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
```

I do understand that Selenium makes this sort of goal very accessible, but certain limitations (such as having to sign into a website, avoiding putting personal details in code, avoiding manual entry of personal details using input) discourage it.

My first step was to use OS to open a new tab in an existing instance of Chrome, one I manually opened, which works great.

```
os.system(f'start chrome.exe {link}')
```

This is where I'm stuck. I browsed through the OS directory, but am not sure exactly what to look for. I'm new to this sort of coding so I'm not sure how to proceed, what modules would be helpful here, or where I should look for further help.

**TL; DR:**

How do I interact (scrape information, navigate page elements, etc...) with a manually opened Chrome browser using Python and Selenium (or other)?

Comment: What about opening Chrome via `selenium`, putting your script on hold, entering the information manually and resume your script?

Comment: @MaximilianPeters That's how I was doing it before, but I'm trying to do it in such a way that the browser has access to Chrome user data, and I think the easiest way to do that is to just interface with an existing instance.

Answer (score 1):

Start chrome with debug port:

`<path>\chrome.exe" --remote-debugging-port=1559`

And in selenium use :

`System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\chromedriver.exe");

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

options.setExperimentalOption("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:1559");

WebDriver browser=new ChromeDriver(options);`
```

Python :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:1559")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
```

Comment: Would you be able to translate this over to Python?

Comment: @AnythingII added

Comment: In my program, I define driver (and will put in your code above subsequently) before I start chrome, I presume that would still work fine. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, Before you create driver object add that option and option to the driver initializer when you call it chrome driver(options)

Comment: I'm still running into some trouble, but I found this and just have no clue how to implement it into my python script. Think you can help? System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "<path-to-chrome-driver>/chromedriver.exe");

Comment: @AnythingII could you eventually solve it? I'm interested in this possible solution but now convinced. Hoping to find something simpler...